# want to save corresponding id in another table...how to use both id and value both in lables?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-spinner

//all judge name

in label's we get different judge-name from judge table in index of get indexes of judge-name means ids....

**Code :**

```
  public List<String> getAlljudge(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

       // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_ID_JUDGE + "," +KEY_NAME_JUDGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS_JUDGE;

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       // looping through all rows and adding to list
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
            labels.indexOf(cursor.getString(0));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       // closing connection
       cursor.close();
       db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
   }
```

further in another table i want to store this id's and selection of judge name through drop down.. actually another layout where a spinner is used where spinner data comes from this `"labels"` when selection of any judge i want to save corresponding id in another table...how to use both id and value both in labels???? help me...

Comment: how to solve it?? plz suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Pass labels via Intent

```
Intent ipass = new Intent(this,Your next Class);
ipass.putStringArrayListExtra("key", labels);
startActivity(ipass);
```

Then In that layout

```
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent iget = getIntent();
labels = iRes.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Hope it work
For spinner operation use this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/